# Apollo codegen redundant types

Tags: graphql, apollo

In apollo/graphql, I have one type Book. I have 2 queries (readBooks, createBook). Both queries return an array of Books.

When I use apollo codegen, I end up with 2 typed files that are very similar.
Is there any more documentation on how the naming is created? I was hoping to reduce the redundancy some how so that in the client app, I can just reference one type.

```
export interface BooksRead_readBooks {
  **typename: "Book";
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
export interface BooksCreate_createBooks {
 **typename: "Book";
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```